# IE double submits data when executing script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Need a little assistance in Jquery /Ajax.

I have multiple forms in one page, once one of them is clicked, It sends data to post.php ++ disables submit button.
I am using following script(s) for that.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (returnedData ) {
         $( '#sidebar' ).load( 'div.php');

        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            $(this).val( "Selected" );
              $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
                 });
    });
</script>
```

Problem that I face, is that it works fine for all browsers, except IE9. (it double submits data….). How can I merge both scripts in one? Problem that I face, is that it works fine for all browsers, except IE9. (it double submits data….). How can I merge both scripts in one? (please note that I have at least 50 forms in this page….)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this to prevent double submit

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return false; " />
```

And to merge the both scripts just do something like this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  $(this).val( "Selected" );

  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: $(this).parents('form:first').serialize(),
        success: function (returnedData ) {
         $( '#sidebar' ).load( 'div.php');

        }
    });
});

</script>
```